# PHP usort - array indexes not moving correctly

Tags: php, usort

I'm trying to order string based on a custom alphabet. I have php code that breaks the file to be sorted into an array of strings. I'm attempting to order each string. The strings are ordering themselves correctly, but they aren't moving around the array correctly. I'm new to php, so I'm hoping someone could show me my errors.

Thanks :)

```
<?php
echo " start ";
        $file = fopen('inFile.txt', "r");
        $firstLine = fgets($file);
echo " hi ";
$x = 0;
while(! feof($file)){
$restOfFile[$x] = fgets($file);
$x++;
}
$firstLine = str_replace(' ','',$firstLine);


fclose($file);
//echo $firstLine;
//print_r( $restOfFile);

function mylst($a,$b){
$pos1 = 0;
$pos2 = 0;
global $firstLine;


if(strlen($a) > strlen($b)){
     $string = $b;
}else{
     $string = $a;
}

for ($i=0;$i<(strlen($string) && $pos1===$pos2); $i++){
     $pos1 = strpos($firstLine,substr($a,1));
     $pos2 = strpos($firstLine,substr($b,1));
}

if ($pos1 === $pos2 && strlen($a) !== strlen($b)){
     return (strlen($a)-strlen($b));
}

  return $pos1-$pos2;
}


echo " BEFORE ";

print_r($restOfFile);

echo " AFTER ";
usort($restOfFile,"mylst");
print_r($restOfFile);


?>
```

Comment: I think I misunderstood what you're trying to do. Could you give a sample of the sort of input you will use and the expected output?

Comment: Of course

Input
`vcawufotrb
laencfuesw
gvtkwekfom
vrsfqictqc
wmcvmjmtet
qetegyqelu
newaxdtjlt
nfrfrwkknj
fzqrvgblov
gkkmgwwwpa`

Output
`newaxdtjlt
nfrfrwkknj
laencfuesw
gkkmgwwwpa
gvtkwekfom
fzqrvgblov
wmcvmjmtet
vcawufotrb
vrsfqictqc
qetegyqelu`

With the alphabet n e d c r h a l g k m z f w j o b v x q y i p u s t

Answer (score 1):

The main problem I think is the [substr()](http://php.net/substr) usage.

```
substr($b,1)
```

Returns everything from the first position to the end of the string. It should be:

```
substr($b, $i, 1)
```

Modified function:

```
function mylst($a,$b){
$pos1 = 0;
$pos2 = 0;
global $firstLine;


$l = (strlen($a) > strlen($b)) ? strlen($b) : strlen($a);

for ( $i = 0; ($i < $l) && ($pos1 === $pos2); $i++){
     $pos1 = strpos($firstLine,substr($a,$i,1));
     $pos2 = strpos($firstLine,substr($b,$i,1));
}

if ($pos1 === $pos2 && strlen($a) !== strlen($b)){
     return (strlen($a)-strlen($b));
}

  return $pos1-$pos2;
}
```